# NullPointerException when trying to get camera parameters

Tags: android, parameters, android-camera

I want to check if the camera flash is turned on or off by getting the camera parameters, but I got an error: `NullPointerException`...

here is my code:

```
 public class FlashLight extends Activity {

    Camera camera;
    Camera.Parameters cp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        if(pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){

            cp = camera.getParameters();

                a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if(cp.getFlashMode().equals(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
                        {
                            lamp("on");
                        }
                        else if(cp.getFlashMode().equals(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
                        {
                            lamp("off");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You never set `camera` to anything. Hence, `camera` is `null`. Use `Camera.open()` to open the `Camera`. Use `close()` to then close the `Camera` when you are done with it.

Comment: @user3194430: Use LogCat and examine the Java stack trace to determine what line has the `NullPointerException`. Edit your question to point out this line.

Comment: @CommonWare how to do that ?